# Can limit come into modulus of a given function?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, absolute-value

Given an extended real valued function $f:R\to \overline{R}$

Is the following true?

$$
\lim_{x \to a} |f(x)| = |\lim_{x \to a}f(x)|
$$

Comment: Are you assuming that the limit on both sides exist?

Comment: Yes! Assuming it exist.

Comment: Ok, please edit your question to include that --very-- important detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $f(x) = 1$ for $x \le a$ and $f(x) = -1$ for $x > a$. Then, $\lim_{x \to a} |f(x)| = 1$, but $|\lim_{x \to a} f(x)|$ does not exist since the left end right limits differ, i.e. 
$$\lim_{x \to a^-} f(x) = 1 \neq -1 = \lim_{x \to a^+} f(x).$$
The claim is true if $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ exists.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the left can exist even if the right does not. Consider the function that is $-1$ at rational numbers and $1$ at irrational numbers.

Comment: Thus this not true in general?